# cryptsetup fails at decrypting logical partition: "Cannot use device /dev/sda5 which is in use (already mapped or mounted)"

Tags: partitioning, encryption, luks, cryptsetup

I've encountered a problem while I was trying to set an encrypted logical partition for personal data. All I did was formating some free space on the same hard disk I installed Kubuntu using the KDE Partition Manager. I read multiples guides online on how to decrypt and use the encrypted partition and pretty much everyone suggests to use the `cryptsetup` command, then mount the partition somewhere in `/` and it should be ready to use. The problem is that whenever I launch the `cryptsetup` command, I receive the following error:

```
Cannot use device /dev/sda5 which is in use (already mapped or mounted)
```

Here is the command I launched:

```
sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sda5 partition-enc --type=luks
```

A not really elegant workaround seemed to be "deactivate" the logical partition in the KDE Partition Manager to make the `cryptsetup` command execute without errors, however, even doing so, the mounting process will give a `unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'`, which means the file system has not been decrypted successfully, I reckon.

Disclaimer: I already searched for similar questions and issues online of course, but no one seems to be solved. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but no guides or discussion I found seems to take this problem into account.

Comment: Looks like the partition you want to use is mounted, isn't it? What does `sudo mount -l` show?

Comment: Hm. Try to find out which process is using this partition `sudo lsof /dev/sda5`.

Comment: @M.Dm. Thank you for your quick reply. 
Sorry, I meesed up the previous messege.
 It isn't mounted, I checked. I've just found it was mapped (whatever it means) so i tried to close it launching
`sudo cryptsetup close luks-103ce2bb-ef55-4ff6-ac5a-dff6b141272f --type=luks`
And open it again and mount it but I could use it (e.g. I couldn't make a new folder).

Also I already tried `sudo lsof /dev/sda5` but it gives no result.

Comment: Try to follow [this](https://linuxconfig.org/basic-guide-to-encrypting-linux-partitions-with-luks) guide. I think you might miss some steps.

Comment: Yesterday, I decided to follow this guide on youtube: `Linux Cryptosetup LUKS Tutorial: Encrypting Directories / Partition / Hard Disks` by Nixcraftcom. It does exactly what the guide you linked says and it works! Thank you for your help!

Comment: KDE Partition Manager would not allow to do anything cryptsetup does not allow. In fact it only calls "cryptsetup close" when you click deactivate. You should first unmount encrypted file system, then you can close luks container.

Comment: grrrr. yuno post answer